# Windows 10 UWP Answer to webview poor PDF performance

Tags: c#, xaml, pdf, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I am currently creating a manuals page for our APP which can be called from many different pages and dependant upon which page calls it is called from it will display the relevant manual for that page. Originally I added Multiple PDFs to this page. However, all of the PDF Files Loaded extremely slowly in the webview. On Top of this when I scrolled down to see other manuals, and then back up to the top of the page, the Manual PDFs at the top of the page would have to reload, taking  even more time. 
The Same PDF files loaded much quicker in IOS & Android, but The windows phone was almost Unusable due to its performance.

**To Help Beat this issue I Converted all of my PDF files to .PNG files. Not only did this Lower the File Size, but it also allowed them to load quicker, and stay loaded on the page!**

However, if Possible I would prefer these manuals to be PDF files. Is there any way to add PDF files to the App, but have them load quickly, and **stay loaded on the page**?

Also, Is anybody else facing the problems that I am when it comes to PDFs being loaded this poorly.

Below is my Code where I add my Manuals:

```
    <ListView x:Name="MyScrollViewer" ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto">
        <ListViewItem>
            <Image Name="HelpManual" Source="{StaticResource BlankPage}" Width="{Binding Path=ViewportWidth, ElementName=MyScrollViewer}"/>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            <Image Name="HelpManual2" Source="{StaticResource BlankPage}" Width="{Binding Path=ViewportWidth, ElementName=MyScrollViewer}"/>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            <Image Name="HelpManual3" Source="{StaticResource BlankPage}" Width="{Binding Path=ViewportWidth, ElementName=MyScrollViewer}"/>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

The source of each PNG Manual is set in a Page Resource as below:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="BlankPage" UriSource="" />
<BitmapImage x:Key="Manual1" UriSource="Assets\AppPages\HelpManuals\App-User-Guide-v1.4_Page_01.png" />
<BitmapImage x:Key="Manual2" UriSource="Assets\AppPages\HelpManuals\App-User-Guide-v1.4_Page_02.png" />
<BitmapImage x:Key="Manual3" UriSource="Assets\AppPages\HelpManuals\App-User-Guide-v1.4_Page_03.png" />
```

The Source of each image is then Changed in the Back Ground C# code from 'BlankPage' (which is nothing), to Whichever Manual is needed. 
The BackGround Code is as follows:

```
  void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lastPage = Frame.BackStack.Last().SourcePageType;

        if (lastPage.Name == "MainPage" || lastPage.Name == "ManualsPage")
        {
            HelpManual.Source = (ImageSource)Resources["Manual1"];
            HelpManual2.Source = (ImageSource)Resources["Manual2"];
            HelpManual3.Source = (ImageSource)Resources["Manual3"];

        }
        else if (lastPage.Name == "BluetoothPage")
        {
            HelpManual.Source = (ImageSource)Resources["Manual1"];
            HelpManual2.Source = (ImageSource)Resources["Manual2"];
            HelpManual3.Source = (ImageSource)Resources["Manual1"];
            HelpManual4.Source = (ImageSource)Resources["Manual4"];
        }
        else if (lastPage.Name == "PowerPage")
        {
            HelpManual.Source = (ImageSource) Resources["Manual3"];
        }
```

Any Help would be greatly Appreciated to help improve PDF loading performance!

Comment: I haven't dealt with this specifically and I don't have an answer to the pdf side, but one quick/easy thing you could do in the meantime is run those png's through compression like [tinyPNG](http://tinypng.com) which will cut your already lowered sizes in half and it takes minutes to do.

Comment: @ChrisW. I didn't know about that site, thanks! Now I've managed to reduce all of my file sizes even further thanks to you.

Comment: No problem, it's a pretty handy site. Cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this can be done.. List only file names and when you tap on that open the file in pdf reader if there is any installed in phone

Comment: You can try with [Windows.Data.Pdf namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.pdf.aspx). It contains classes for converting a page in a Portable Document Format (PDF) document to an image file. Using this you can keep your manuals to be PDF files and show them in images. There is also a [PDF document sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/PdfDocument) in GitHub, you can have a check.

Comment: @LovetoCode I have tried two PDF viewers, the primary one being Adobe Acrobat Reader. Opening PDFs even downloaded outside of my app, the PDF rendering performance is incredibly poor. In comparison to opening PDFs in my Android / IOS app which is written non-native in apache Cordova it is incredibly poor performance.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Hi Jay, thank you for your input, I am looking into the example now to see how it works and will test with my current test PDF. I will report my findings today.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT I have tried the GitHub solution & unfortunately for me it was still poor, The PDF which I loaded took a very long time and I'm really looking for quick response. Thank you very much still.

Comment: Could you share the PDF you've used for test? I used https://www.microsoft.com/about/mspreview/windows8/windows8_rp_product_guide.pdf for test and in my said, the performance is OK.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT [link](https://swiftportal.azurewebsites.net/Content/AppUserManual/AppUserGuidev1.2.pdf)  is the hosted location we get the pdf from. Please note I do have a much smaller version of this PDF now (986kb). But this is the version supplied by the company and they place it in the folder and our Apps connect to it and refer to it for the manuals pages. The Android and ios platform can both handle this 11.3mb file easily.